# Scion for GHC 7.0.2

Tags: haskell, ide

Is there a repository of scion, which is ready for GHC 7.0.2?

I found

[hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/scion) linking to [nominolo's scion](https://github.com/nominolo/scion) (stops at GHC 6.12) but there are 46 forks, don't know which is populuar for 7.0.2...

If there is none... might I install GHC 6.12 in parallel to GHC 7.0.2?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Are you interested in Scion itself, or do you plan on using Scion in combination with an Editor such as Emacs or VIM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a flag to scion to tell it to build with the proper version of Scion:

cabal configure -fcabal_1_10

This is done automatically by EclipseFP when building scion (we know with cabal to use and which version it is.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at [scion's network graph](https://github.com/nominolo/scion/network), I see that [this fork](https://github.com/JPMoresmau/scion) (presumably used in EclipseFP) is being actively worked on (last commit dates from 2011-05-12) and includes ["GHC 7 support"](https://github.com/JPMoresmau/scion/commit/1eb5eb6f27602d99b1c30caa5ae3b53586d82392). Thomas's repo also contains a [`scion-2nd-attempt`](https://github.com/nominolo/scion/commits/scion-2nd-attempt) branch which has been updated recently. I can't comment on stability though, as I don't use scion myself - you should ask the developers.

Comment: Perfect information, Thomas's repo branch "scion-2nd-attempt" is compiling under GHC 7.0.2.  (in combination with https://github.com/nominolo/atto-lisp.git  v0.2), merci beaucoup!